# Android print this to the left?

Tags: java, android

```
TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TextView textview = new TextView(this);
textview.setText(text.getText());
//  textview.getTextColors(R.color.)
textview.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

tr1.addView(textview);
chatbox.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

How can i print this code when it adds the view to the left of the TableLayout

Comment: tr1.addView(textview);
            chatbox.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: Can you please rephrase? What do mean by "print this code"?

Comment: In the TableLayout it prints out the text on the left of it in yellow how can i do the same but make it go to the right?

Comment: set the textview gravity to the right..  textview.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

Comment: Thanks sandhya, please make that a reply so i can check mark you

Comment: i added as the answer.plz check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Textview Gravity to the Right...

```
   textview.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```